# AWK: field separator contains a '+'

Tags: shell, awk

```
echo -n 'a001~!+rr001~!+1~!+TEST DATA 1' | awk 'BEGIN {FS="~!+"} {print $2}'
```

I have the field separator set to "~!+" and want to print the second field.
AWK prints an extraneous + with rr001 as +rr001 .

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `-F '~!\+'`; the single quotes are necessary (or, if you use double quotes, write `-F "~!\\+"` (but it is simpler to use single quotes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $ echo -n 'a001~!+rr001~!+1~!+TEST DATA 1' | awk 'BEGIN {FS="~!\\+"} {print $2}' 
rr001
```

Double escaping also seems to do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your match criteria '~!+' is a regular expression.

From the documentation: "[+   This symbol](http://www.gnu.org/manual/gawk/html_node/Regexp-Operators.html#Regexp-Operators) is similar to ‘*’, except that the preceding expression must be matched at least once. This means that ‘wh+y’ would match ‘why’ and ‘whhy’, but not ‘wy’, whereas ‘wh*y’ would match all three of these strings."

So essentially you are asking to match ~! or ~!!, etc. So you are not matching on the + at all. This is why you see the + in the output. You should be able to use '`~!\\+`' to get your expression to work

Answer (score 0):

do it another way

```
$ echo 'a001~!+rr001~!+1~!+TEST DATA 1' | awk -F"+" '{gsub(/~!$/,"",$2);print $2}'
rr001
```

or this

```
$ echo  'a001~!+rr001~!+1~!+TEST DATA 1' | awk -F"[~][!][+]" '{print $2}'
rr001
```

or

```
$ echo  'a001~!+rr001~!+1~!+TEST DATA 1' | awk -F'~!\\+' '{print $2}'
rr001
```

Comment: The first proposed solution is not a good idea - for multiple reasons.  The second will work, but is overkill compared to fixing the regex to '`~!\+`'.  Using '-F' is nicer than setting FS in a BEGIN block, but you should use single quotes around it rather than double quotes - especially when it contains a backslash.

Comment: "The first proposed solution is not a good idea" -- agreed indeed!!